# Pass authentication in the backend through NGINX using a user certificate and private key

Tags: ssl, nginx, certificate, reverse-proxy

My program on Golang can't work with user certificate (http client) due unsupported old tls algorithms. I want to solve it with reverse proxy using nginx. Here is a pic describes thoughted scheme https://ibb.co/Jxcy52G .

[client] ----> [NGINX:80] ----(proxy pass using cert,privkey)----> [TOMCAT:8443]

https://TOMCAT:8443 requires authentication with a client certificate. I want to hide this fact from my app. App must not be required to provide a client certificate. Instead, I would like NGINX to use a certificate that's stored on the server.

My nginx.conf config:

```
    server {
      listen 80;
     # server_name _;

      location / {
        proxy_ssl_certificate       "cert.pem";
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key   "key.pem";
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
#       proxy_ssl_verify       off;
        proxy_ssl_name "iscs.telecomtest.ru";

                proxy_read_timeout 300;
                proxy_send_timeout 300;

        proxy_pass  https://195.11.xx.16:8443;
        proxy_buffering off;

      }
    }
```

When i try to open page http://my-nginx:80/, I get:

```
2019/06/18 15:16:22 [error] 25896#14556: *133 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /? HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://195.11.xx.16/?", host: "127.0.0.1:19101"
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks right to me except that your diagram and example say nginx port is 80 but your config says 19101. If both of these are correct you aren't actually using that server block and need to look elsewhere. If they are actually the same, that config (modified to my hosts, ports and cert&keys) **works for me**, on nginx-1.12.2 and (since I don't have Tomcat set up) using both Java-test and OpenSSL-test backends; I suggest you look at the server log(s) and see what it thinks the problem is.

Comment: the ports and config actualy is the same. Logs attached to post, please see above.```*133 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream...```

Comment: I meant log(s) for the server _for this connection_, not nginx; it is generically the backend or upstream, and in your case Tomcat.